# JavaFX: Disable most of Stage before data ready

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding

I'm facing quite simple, but general problem.

## Problem setup

I have **JavaFX** application with main window (main stage). This stage works with *some* (keep it general) data. The data may be *somehow* loaded at the startup (for instance from server, database, XML file). The source of data (server adress, database name, XML file path) are to be **prompted from user**. (Keep in mind, that user can cancel the input and the data won't be loaded.)

Since I would like to show the stage up for the user (to get acquainted with the app and possibly browse the help) and then, by menu `File -> Load data`, let him to load the data.

But since the stage depends mostly on the data, I need **to disable most of the controls** until the user properly loads the data and makes the stage useable.

## Question

Here arises dilema I cannot solve. AFAIK, I have two options, how to make most of stage disabled until the data are properly ready:

1. ### Bind disabled with "or data not loaded"

   The more JavaFX-binding-friendly solution is to have boolean property like `dataNotReadyProperty` and then, when the controller is beeing initialized use things like:

   ```
    private void init() { // call from initialize method
      // ....
      doFooButton.disableProperty().bind(
        Bindings.or(
          dataProperty().get().cannotBeFooDoneProperty(),
          dataNotReadyProperty()
        )
      );
      // ....
    }
   ```

As you can see, this code is quite ugly and long (especialy when some controls' disability is given by additional `or` or `and`).

2. ## Disable and bind when data ready

   The second option is to simply disable everything at startup (or even within the FXML). And also set up change listener for the `dataProperty` and when the data is loaded, do the proper initialization of bindings. Written in code:

   ```
    private void init() { // call from initialize method
      // ....
      doFooButton.setDisabled(true);
      // ....
      dataProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (oldValue == null && newValue != null) {
          runInitialization();
        }
      });
    }

    private void runInitialization() {
      // ....
      doFooButton.disableProperty().bind(
        dataProperty().get().cannotBeFooDoneProperty());
      // ....
    }
   ```

This solution splits initialization into two, but the "real" initialization here is kept simple and understandable. Also, I am forced to modify each control twice.

## Conclusions

What would you prefer? Do you have another suggestions, how to solve this situation?

## Additional info

- the stage does need any more initialization than the bindings of disabled properties
- once the data is loaded, it cannot be "unloaded" (it can be only reloaded by other one)
- there is approx. 20 controls to be disabled on startup and 4 to be accessible.

Comment: Try putting all the controls that need to be disabled in a pane/group(I personally have never tried this with a group) and disable the pane/group.

Comment: This probably won’t help a lot, but [BooleanProperty inherits its own or(…) method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanExpression.html#or%28javafx.beans.value.ObservableBooleanValue%29).  No need to use the Bindings class, you can just do `property1.or(property2)`.

Comment: Since the source of your data is to be decided from the user, I would advice to keep this view (where you accept source information) as your default view. Once the user fills the necessary information and submits it, you can load the new view with data.

Comment: @Sedrick: good point, may work, but I need selective enable some of controls of the pane.

Comment: @VGR I know, but some of mine binding expressions are quite complicated and will be unreadable or event impossible to create this way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i decided to use solution base on the @ItachiUchiha's answer.

**I've created two different Panes**, one for proper work with data, another one with just label like: "Load data to start work" and load button.

The remaining (just about 5 of them) controls i disabled/enabled by bindings (option 1). So the amount of "ugly" code decreased rapidly.